# Unable to set flutter environment variable in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, flutter, environment-variables, ubuntu-18.04

As stated on flutter's website [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#update-your-path), I tried setting the environment variable in my Ubuntu 18.10 system. I have saved command in `.bashrc` but when I source it to run in terminal or run `flutter doctor` command in a new terminal, it says `flutter: command not found`.

Surprisingly, when I tried the following command, it worked perfectly but it's temporary:

```sh
export PATH="$PATH:`pwd`/flutter/bin"
```

I want a permanent solution for setting the environment variable.

Output on `echo $PATH`:

```sh
/snap/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

Update: I have added `echo "$PATH"` in `.bashrc` right after the export PATH command and it does have a flutter path printed in the terminal when I execute `source ~/.bashrc` but when I enter flutter doctor after that, it still doesn't work!

Comment: I have also tried [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#update-path-directly) one and faced the same issue.

Comment: Also, I have my `.bashrc` already which also have alias commands which I use very often. They are working fine. I think the problem is with flutter itself.

Comment: Could you show exactly what the line in your .bashrc file looks like? And can you confirm you followed step 4 by running `source ~/.bashrc`?

Comment: @MichaelDavies Thanks for coming up for help. I have updated the question. I hope it clears the problem.

Comment: No problem. I see you solved it now. Have fun.

Answer (score 1):

You are nearly there actually. In your `~/.bashrc` file, write the absolute path to `flutter/bin`. Don't use `pwd` to resolve the working directory dynamically, because the working directory when the machine is booting up is not necessarily the same as the one you are currently using. To see the full path to `flutter/bin`, do this from your current directory:

```sh
echo "`pwd`/flutter/bin`
```

Then write the following at the end of your `~/.bashrc` file:

```sh
export PATH=$PATH:<full path to flutter/bin>
```

Then run the following command:

```sh
source ~/.bashrc
```

After that, you should be able to run the `flutter` command, and the command should also be available every time you start up your machine and ssh into it.

Comment: That's what I got from ```echo `pwd`/flutter/bin``` -> `/home/techmirtz/flutter/bin`. I pasted the same in `.bashrc` as `export PATH="$PATH:/home/techmirtz/flutter/bin"` and then used `source  ~/.bashrc`. But still, it's not working.

Comment: Update: I have added `echo "$PATH"` in `.bashrc` right after the flutter export PATH command and it does have a flutter path printed in the terminal when I execute `source ~/.bashrc` but when I enter `flutter doctor` after that, it still doesn't work!

Comment: The issue has been resolved. I had a `source` command to set the value of `PATH` to something else which excluded flutter there in the `.bashrc` file somewhere after the flutter PATH command which actually sets the path without the flutter at the end of the `.bashrc` overwriting the flutter path.